# Write a function that returns boolean value for only valid numbers or string of valid numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, lodash

Here is a function which accepts 'value' and returns a true and false based on the fact its number or not. But it accepts '1....2' too and returns true which is a problem.
I am confused on how to deal with it.

```
const boolean = (value, schema) => {
return (
    value === false ||
    value === true ||
    value === "true" ||
    value === "false" ||
    value === "0" ||
    value === "1"
);
};

const float = (value, schema) => {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(value));
};
```

Comment: Tried using 'lodash-contrib'. Got confused during implementation.

Comment: "*it accepts '1....2' too and returns true*" - no it doesn't, `boolean('1....2')` is `false`?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `schema` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

this worked.
without using lodash-contrib

```
const float = (value, schema) => {
return !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value); };
```